# Rotating a RectF on an Android canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I've been searching around and can't seem to find a fix for this. I'm trying to display a gun (as a RectF) that's in space on the canvas that is automatically rotating with the tick method. I'm saving the canvas, rotating it by the gun angle, then drawing the rectangle, and then restoring the canvas inside of the tick method... but it only rotates the gun one time. Anybody have an idea of how to make it rotate continuously? Thanks!

---

This question was answered in the comments below if anybody is searching for something similar.

```
    public class SpaceAnimator implements Animator {

// constants
private static final int FRAME_INTERVAL = 60; // animation-frame interval, in milliseconds
private static final int BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK; // background color

// paint objects
private Paint whitePaint;
private Paint yellowPaint;
private Paint bluePaint;

//random number generator
Random randomGen = new Random();

//PointF array to hold star positions 
ArrayList<PointF> stars = new ArrayList<PointF>();

//Number of stars
int numberOfStars = 100;

//PointFs for center of the sun and angle of gun
PointF centerOfSun1 = new PointF(300,200);
float angleOfGun = 1;


// constructor
public SpaceAnimator() {

    //Create a white paint object
    whitePaint = new Paint();
    whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    //Create a yellow paint object
    yellowPaint = new Paint();
    yellowPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 

    //create a blue paint object
    bluePaint = new Paint();
    bluePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    //Set position of the stars
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
    {
        int randStarX = randomGen.nextInt(100); //random X initial position
        int randStarY = randomGen.nextInt(100); //random Y initial position
        stars.add(new PointF(randStarX, randStarY)); //set X and Y positions
    }

}

/**
 * Interval between animation frames
 * 
 * @return the time interval between frames, in milliseconds.
 */
public int interval() {
    return FRAME_INTERVAL;
}

/**
 * The background color.
 * 
 * @return the background color onto which we will draw the image.
 */
public int backgroundColor() {
    // create/return the background color
    return BACKGROUND_COLOR;
}

/**
 * Action to perform on clock tick
 * 
 * @param g the canvas object on which to draw
 */
public void tick(Canvas g) {

    int height = g.getHeight();
    int width = g.getWidth();

    //draw the stars
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
    {
        g.drawCircle(stars.get(i).x/100 * width, stars.get(i).y/100 * height, randomGen.nextInt(2), whitePaint);
    }

    //draw the first sun
    g.drawCircle(centerOfSun1.x, centerOfSun1.y, 40, yellowPaint);

    //rotate/draw the gun
    g.save();
    g.rotate(angleOfGun);
    g.drawRect(new RectF(width/2 - 20, height/2 - 20, width/2 + 20, height/2 + 20), bluePaint);
    g.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the code you've posted is incrementing (or decrementing) angleOfGun.

If that's true, it makes sense that you'll only "see" it rotate the first time by 1 degree and then stick there.  You'll need to add a line like this to the end of your tick method:

```
angleOfGun = (angleOfGun + 1) % 360;
```

Comment: Okay, that helped a bunch, thank you. Now, I just need to figure out how to get the gun to rotate around a fixed spot, because it's now rotating in a circle as if it were orbiting something.

Comment: Use the rotate(float degrees, float px, float py) method to rotate around the center point of your gun rect.

Comment: Hey Michael, I'm trying to do something similar to rotating the gun. I'm trying to shoot some balls out of the gun, at the guns angle, but have them shoot straight. Whenever they shoot out, they keep rotating along with the gun, as if they are orbiting. Any suggestions?

I've tried not restoring the canvas, so that I can just shoot them in a straight line after the rotation but it's not coming together.